# I can't clean space to login into ubuntu

Tags: disk

Today I tried to install "wine", and it installed correctly, after I restarted back to Windows to get my exe file and it already happened to me that the partitioned is full, so I booted to recovery mode, but the clean is not cleaning anything, and I tried to mount the system drive as a read write, but it's not saying anything, can you help me pls?

My system:
Ubuntu 16.04
120 GB SSD
The partition of Ubuntu is 10 GB

Comment: now after a reboot i get:

Comment: "error: unknown filesystem."

Comment: "Entering rescue mode..."

Comment: "grub rescue>_"

Comment: That's not a 'disk full' error. 'unknown filesystem' is sometimes very bad news. Boot from a LiveUSB and backup your data immediately. Might be salvageable (or worthwhile to salvage), might not.